# Where to insert a GROUP BY in a complex PostgreSQL query which aggregate two tables

Tags: sql, postgresql

In the below PSQL query I need to add a `GROUP BY member.id` but I have difficulties to where to put it as always saying syntax error on the `GROUP BY`.
The query is aggregating 2 tables and update message excluding where we have a `USER` type. The script complains about the missing `GROUP BY member.id` but have no idea at the moment where to put it and need ideas.

```
update
    message m
set
    status = 'DEFAULT'
where
    status = 'PENDING'
    and conversation_id = '1'
    and not exists (
    select
        1
    from
        "member"
    having
        id = m.member_id
        and origin_type = 'USER')
    and m.updated_at < (
    select
        max(m.updated_at)
    from
        message
    having
        conversation_id = m.conversation_id
        and origin_type = 'USER')
```

The tables where I'm doing this as screenshot

Message

[image: Message table]

Member

[image: Member]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there are some mistakes below.

- `having` => `where`
- `max(m.updated_at)` => `max(updated_at)`
- `and origin_type = 'USER'` really needs?

The following query will not result in an error.
However, I think the query is not your desired one.

```
update
    message m
set
    status = 'DEFAULT'
where
    status = 'PENDING'
    and conversation_id = '1'
    and not exists (
    select
        1
    from
        "member"
    --having
    where
        id = m.member_id
        and origin_type = 'USER')
    and m.updated_at < (
    select
        --max(m.updated_at)
        max(updated_at)
    from
        message
    --having
    where
        conversation_id = m.conversation_id
        --and origin_type = 'USER')
        )
```

Answer (score 1):

Usually `GROUP BY` clause is placed between `WHERE` and `HAVING` statements (reference [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/sql-select.html)).

In your case, however, I believe you just need to substitute your 'HAVING`statements with`WHERE`.

The `WHERE` clause defines filters on the original dataset pre-aggregations.
The `HAVING` clause defines filters on the original dataset post-aggregation and usually is dedicated to aggregated result filtering.

In your case, since you just want to filter the rows in the original dataset pre-aggregation, `WHERE` should be used

```
update
    message m
set
    status = 'DEFAULT'
where
    status = 'PENDING'
    and conversation_id = '1'
    and not exists (
    select
        1
    from
        "member"
    WHERE
        id = m.member_id
        and origin_type = 'USER')
    and m.updated_at < (
    select
        max(m.updated_at)
    from
        message
    WHERE
        conversation_id = m.conversation_id
        and origin_type = 'USER')
```

Comment: In this I'm getting the following error

`
ERROR: aggregate functions are not allowed in WHERE
`

Answer (score 1):

According to the SQL syntax the GROUP BY should come prior to the HAVING. But are you sure that the problem is that you are missing the GROUP BY? Can it be instead that the problem that you should use WHERE instead of the HAVING? For me this seams to make much more sence.

```
update
    message m
set
    status = 'DEFAULT'
where
    status = 'PENDING'
    and conversation_id = '1'
    and not exists (
       select
           1
       from
           "member"
       where 
           id = m.member_id
           and origin_type = 'USER'
    )
    and m.updated_at < (
       select
           max(m.updated_at)
       from
           message
       where
           conversation_id = m.conversation_id
           and origin_type = 'USER'
    )
```

Comment: In this I'm getting the following error

```
ERROR: aggregate functions are not allowed in WHERE
```